# Microsoft Authentication loop with ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application deployed on Azure which suffers from an authentication loop.

At first I discovered that it was an `HTTP` problem, so I forced `HTTPS` from Azure. The problem went away, but it reappears after a while after the deploy. Deploying again (the same version) resolves the loop, which comes back after a while. What can it be? What should I look for?

So far I've tried to include the following in my `Web.config`

```
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="false"></add>
```

And this in my `Startup.auth.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
        });
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });
}
```

I've created the MVC 5 project by specifying login with organization account, and enabled the same thing in the deploy profile:

[image: Deploy settings]

I don't know what else to try, help.

Comment: Not enough information. Does it loop every time for any user (after a while) or just sometimes and for someone? Try to start with a new incognito window and recheck. Could you track the redirects and add to the question?

Comment: After a while for every user who's not logged in anymore. Incognito mode loops, normal mode too, across every browser. I would give more details but seriously I can't narrow it down to a pattern, not now. So ask as many questions you want, maybe it will point me to the right direction....

Comment: try to add app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            return next();
        }); somewhere at the beginning of the middleware chain, as you said forcing https on Azure level affected the behavior.

Comment: also try to set `CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()` in both CookieAuthenticationOptions and OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions

Comment: As you mentioned that the authentication loop would come back after a while, maybe it caused by cookie expire time? Does it could work correctly locally?

Answer (score 1):

The same here, I'm out off options on this one. You just cannot reproduce this to find the exact cause.

This is what I did in the meantime:

**AuthStartup.cs:**

> ```
> app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
> {
>     CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never
> });
> ```

**Global.asax.cs**

> ```
> protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
>     Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] +
>     httpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
> }
> ```

**Overriding the Authorize Attribute:**

> ```
> public class AuthorizeFromHTTPAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
> {
>    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
>    {
>        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
>        {
>            UriBuilder redirectUrl = new UriBuilder(
>               filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url);
>            redirectUrl.Scheme = "HTTPS";
>            redirectUrl.Port = 443;
>            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl.ToString());
>            return;
>        }
>        else
>        {
>            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```

A new publish from Visual Studio to Azure solves it for a certain period. So is this something serverside??

Working InPrivate or InCongnito does not solve it either. Cleaning up your cookies either...

Comment: After one week of testing with the custom "SystemWebCookieManager", I'm hopefull that this is working now :-) So far, so good and still working...

more info: [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2016/08/25/owin-cookies-signin-error-with-ad-fs/)